# Is there Any Off-The-Shelf Json Serialization helper class in .NET BCL?

Tags: .net, json, serialization

I need to serialize/de-serialize some objects into/from string and transfer them as just opaque data. I can use XmlSerializer to do it, but generated string looks clumsy and long. So, is there any concise Serializer available in .NET?

The first thing coming to my mind is that perhaps .NET should have JSON Serializer, but I cannot find it. Is there any off-the-shelf approach in .NET to convert object to/from concise string?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two;

- [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) in 3.5
- [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) in 3.5 SP1

In the traditional way, they aren't 100% compatible with each-other, especially re `DateTime`; DCJS uses (IIRC) a literal string; JSS uses `new` - and neither can read t'other correctly.

Of course, if the text if opaque, you could also use any concise binary serializer, and simply base-64 encode it; for example, [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) is pretty terse. But using JSON minimizes the external code needed at each end, so may well be your best bet.

Comment: According to MSDN, JavaScriptSerializer is in System.Web.Extensions.dll which is available in .NET 3.5, not necessarily .NET 3.5 SP1.

Comment: IIRC, it has been marked obsolete and just recently been "un-deprecated" with 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 10):

[Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) is a JSON library for .NET. It is available in CodePlex.

Answer (score 4):

I have a **very fast** open source [JsonSerializer](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344) available that can serialize any POCO or DataContract type, including Interfaces anonymous and late bound types, etc.

Basic Example

```
var customer = new Customer { Name="Joe Bloggs", Age=31 };
var json = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(customer);
var fromJson = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Customer>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

[LINQ To Json](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm) can serialize and deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

just use your own api.. its easy to create json.. but you can also use JSON libraries like JSON.NET..

happy coding

Answer (score 0):

[JsonFx.NET](http://jsonfx.net/download/#json) has an open-source serializer which allows serialization to/from strongly typed classes which might be what you're looking for.  You can control how dates are serialized and override many aspects of the serialization.  It even interacts well with Linq by supporting serialization of anonymous objects.  The API works just like .NET XML serialization.