# String Split Logic C#

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a REST service that returns me a JSON with a string. This string is an aggregation of a several words. When combining these strings I use a '/' to later split it by the separator.

e.g:-
The json string I am getting- AAA/BBB/CCC (I am reading this values from the DB)

In the UI I am spiting this string from the separator '/' which I introduced to come up with a business logic.

My problem is the separator i introduce '/' is something that the user can even enter. So for an example if user too enters the '/' in to one of the strings then my JSON would be something like below

e.g :- AAA/BBB/CC/C (/ after the two Cs is entered by the user)

Then my string split logic is wrong as I also uses the same value to split the string

What should be the ideal way to handle this kind of a Issue. Im using .NET C#

Ideally I want a way to combine my string and split the string based on something that end user would never enter

Comment: Why cant you use a diff seprator or restrict user from entering your seprator ?

Comment: First of all why save combined string to DB? Knowledge about DB normal forms would be useful.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't return an object from your JSON? Such as an array? `['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']`? It should easy to generate from C#, and it's just as easy to read/generate from Javascript.

Comment: Or you could URL encode them..

Comment: Try another separator like for example '~' That is one that is not used a lot. Or you can try a combined seperator like this for example '~/~'.

Comment: you mean like a control character?

Comment: JSON does cater for the concept of arrays or collections.

Comment: if you really need to do this way make separator be extra ordinary for example `-]\[-` then in application before split you will need to use `Replace` method of string to replace your 5 char separator to one for example `yourValue.Replace("-]\[-","$");` and then do `Split('$')` or any other less posible character used by user

Comment: or you can use a char that's not supported by the key board. just write the int value converted to char.

Comment: @harry180 Pick a really unusual separator without an escaping mechanism, and you will learn a lesson in just how really unusual users can be :)

Comment: @Jon I know that users are at most of cases 'retarded' if you have to make idiot proof app then don't use strings at all or make good validations on every input in your applications. even then You won't eliminate all posibilitys but 90% of them is better than 0 ;) you can use '†' separator (alt+01414 on numeric keyboard);P

Comment: @harry180 Oh, the cases I'm thinking of is when the users didn't do "that thing no users will ever do" because they were stupid, but actually had a perfectly good reason. It's amazing just how convoluted a "thing no user will ever do", they'll do. (Not a criticism of your approach, but an observation of Sod's Law).

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to not store the collection as a scalar value. You could model this in the database with a one-to-many relationship, or you could serialize the collection as XML for example and store this in a single column.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use a string to represent an array. You should return a JSON `['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'etc']`. You can use any JSON library to generate it from C# (if you're using MVC3 you can easily `return Json(...)` an array).

As far as the Javascript goes, you get an array you can easily use. Also, posting it back should be quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, and writing your own serialization code. Why not use a standard JSON library to do the serialization for you.

JSON caters for the concept of arrays or collections already and is designed to escape its own delimiters. There is no need to add you own propriety format into the middle of some standard JSON.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391157/is-there-any-off-the-shelf-json-serialization-helper-class-in-net-bcl) already deals with the JSON serializer selection problem.

---

Just store the strings on your object as some `IEnumerable<string>`. They probably come that way out of your data model anyway.

Answer (score 0):

add a '/' before the '/'. the extra '/' well indicate that you should handle this as a char instead of a separator flag. the split you could do with [regex](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-split)

Comment: The users could type `'//'` in their strings, still. I don't think this would solve the problem.

Comment: and this well torn into "////" so you know that neither of them are split flags.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like,combine string using

> string S='AAA','BBB','CCC'

than in code you can write like

> string[] ary=S.Replace("|","Pipe;").Replace("','","|").Split('|')
>       ary[0] = ary[0].Replace("Pipe;","|")

Comment: and what happens if the user types a ',' or "Pipe;"?

Comment: take one separator that cant b entered from keyboard like
£

Comment: Which is a key on almost every keyboard in Britain and Ireland, is on the US-International Keyboard, on a large number of other keyboards, and has some means of composing it on the majority of keyboards. Even if it wasn't on a keyboard, if a user has to go to the effort of copy-paste to write £ and they want to write £, they will.

Comment: yeah, much better to use `$` (joking).

Comment: Because users will never copy-paste from something with multiple lines?
I think \u001F is a safer bet, though still best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

If you are POSTing or PUTting this string, then don't roll your own encoding like this at all. We have XML and JSON already defined, and while people may argue their pros and cons endlessly, they both work, so use one of them.

If you are GETting with this string in the URI (a better choice when it's naturally a GET, a worse to the point of being bug-prone choice when it isn't), then application/x-www-form-urlencoded is well defined for exactly this use: `item=AAA&item=BBB&item=CCC` with the `&` and `=` from that not uri-encoded, but any `&` or `=` (and any other character that is restricted in URIs) encoded in the normal way (work out the UTF-8 of the character and add each octet's value after a `%` so e.g `=` is `%3D`, `ë` is `%C3%AB` and so on.

If you really need to stick with your basic approach, then U+001F is a control character that traditionally has the purpose of separating fields at the lowest level (U+001E, U+001D and U+001C being used at increasingly higher levels of separating groups of fields) and doesn't appear on most keyboards (and anyone nerdy enough and old-school to have a keyboard set up to type them, expects them to separate fields). I don't recommend taking this 1960s approach to a 2012 problem though if you can possibly avoid it (though I think computers in the US are still mandated by President Johnson to support those characters!)

And for the love of Ada Lovelace, don't store the encoded string in the database if you can at all avoid it (except perhaps in a logging table that is just to record a log of what was sent for diagnostic purposes). Store separate fields in the db, as separate fields. Normalisation is a 1960s approach that **is** still relevant in 2012.